# Url.Action to show page no in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Trying like this

```
 Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { page = 5 })
```

is giving me url like

```
/Home/Index?page=5
```

How to get a url like this

```
/Home/Index/5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PagedRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{page}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And be careful with the default route (the one that uses an `id`) as it is similar. You will might need to put this custom route before the default one or remove the default route as it rarely be hit under those circumstances.

I would recommend you going through the [Routing tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) to gather deeper understanding of how they work.